# Whitespace being added unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Only on Motorola G6 I'm having a problem with special characters.

When the page finishes rendering, a blank space is automatically added before the special character.

I tested on other devices, android, iphone and it worked normally.

In Xiaomi Mi A1, chrome:

[image: mi a1 correctly behavior]

In Moto G6, chrome too:

[image: moto g6 wrong behavior]

Here's the code of the component that is rendered:

```
<styles.Content>
    {!!orders.length &&
      orders.map((item, idx) => (
        <styles.InnerBlock
          id={`order-details-${idx}`}
          key={item.id}
          to={`${ROUTES.ORDER_DETAILS}/${item.id}`}
        >
          <styles.LeftInfo>
            <styles.Date>
              {moment(item.lastChangeTimestamp).format('DD [de] MMMM / YYYY')}
            </styles.Date>
            <styles.Hour>{moment(item.lastChangeTimestamp).format('HH:mm')}</styles.Hour>
          </styles.LeftInfo>
          <styles.RightInfo>
            {formatPrice(item.total)} {/*Here*/}
            <ArrowIcon direction="right" />
          </styles.RightInfo>
        </styles.InnerBlock>
      ))}
</styles.Content>
```

The `formatPrice` function just returns the formatted value e.g: `R$ 10,00`

I already tested commenting the function and made sure that the problem is not in it.

**Edit:** Inspecting the element in the browser, I noticed the following difference:

Normal behavior (Mi A1):

[image]

Wrong (G6):

[image]

Has anyone ever experienced this? In chrome on pc works normally too.

Comment: my guess is it is whitespace between tags

Comment: to narrow down the scope, you can try to just return a hard coded string of "R$ 10.00" from formatPrice to make sure that it is not formatPrice that's doing it (hoping that it is not calling any localization/locale function in there)

Comment: @BillCheng I did that, keep adding the space, I will edit the question and add what appears when inspecting the elements.